# Building trouble with hindent on Debian 8

Tags: haskell, indentation, ghc, cabal

I tried to build **hindent-4.4.0** on debian 8 with GHC-7.6.3 by performing a `cabal install hindent` and I had the following problems :

**1. First problem**

My build stop with this errors :

```
src/Descriptive/JSON.hs:199:33: Not in scope: `floatingOrInteger'
src/Descriptive/JSON.hs:213:39: Not in scope: `toRealFloat'
```

After some research, I reinstalled `scientific-0.3.3.8` lib with `cabal install scientific` (The lib provided with Debian 8 seems to have a problem )

After that, The build of **hindent** has continue until the...

**2. Second problem**

I get this error message :

```
src/HIndent/Pretty.hs:88:31:
    Expecting one more argument to `ast'
    In the class declaration for `Pretty'
```

I suspected a mismatching module version number and tried to install the most recent version of `hindent-4.4.2` manually by downloading the archive from **hackage**.

I performed the standard `cabal install` which leads me to the ...

**3. Third problem**

Cabal is rejecting the package due to incompatible **base** version :

```
rejecting: base-4.6.0.1/installed-8aa... (conflict: hindent => base>=4.7 && <5)
```

and most other versions of **hindent** seems incompatible with base-4.6.

**Do you know how to build any version of hindent on debian 8?**

Comment: You could try specifically installing `hindent-4.4.0` which has more lax `base` version requirements. Also, GHC 7.6.3 is now two major versions behind the current stable release, so it might be time to upgrade.